# There is a way to limit the number of RPC requests per second of the web3.js library?

Tags: web3.js, rpc, data

I am currently doing a script to retrieve data, I have a personal RPC that accepts 600 calls/second, but my script is making more than 600 calls/second using the getParsedTransactions() method via the web3.js library, so my question is: Is there a way to limit the number of calls/second?

Comment: are you using getParsedTransactions() to process 600 signatures, or are you running it 600 times once-per-signature? You should just give it less signatures to process at a time, it's not web3.js's responsibility to go slower for you. If you are processing batches of signatures just make them smaller. Almost always web3 will let you `limit` a large result set

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to do this by using the `batchSize` parameter in the `provider.send` function to reduce the number of requests made in a single batch, this will assist the number of request by second made.

```
const setProvider = new SolanaWeb3Provider('https://testnet.solana.com',{batchSize = 1});

const makeRequests = [
   //Your Request
];

setProvider.send(makeRequests, (err, res) => {
  if(err){
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  // Deal with any response

});
```